# How to create an array where each element is equal to its row number?

Tags: python, numpy, row, element

I was wondering how I can assign each element in an array to be equal to its row number.
For example an array of,

```
Row number: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
Elementnum: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

import numpy as np
array=np.ones(10)
#What next?
```

This will be done with large row numbers of n=1000 so I won't manually be able to do it.

Thanks

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html ?

Answer (score 1):

`np.arange(1, 1000)` if you want a 1-based numbering.

Comment: `1000+1` though ;)